# Not detecting correct types

Tags: typescript

In the following code, why is the callback assuming `string | number | boolean` as the type instead of detecting the exact type based on the property that is being passed as the first argument of `carWithListener.on` function?

```
const car = {
    paint: "red",
    tires: "mrf",
    brakes: "disk",
    bluetooth: true,
    mileage: 7.45
}

type PropChangeListener<T> = {
    on<Key extends string & keyof T>(
        prop: `on${Capitalize<Key>}Changed`, 
        callback: (val: T[Key]) => T[Key]
    ): void
}

declare function registerForChanges<T>(obj: T): PropChangeListener<T>
const carWithListener = registerForChanges(car);
carWithListener.on("onBluetoothChanged", (val: boolean) => !val)
```

Comment: Does this help? type PropChangeListener<T, V> = {
    on<Key extends string & keyof T>(
        prop: \`on${Capitalize<Key>}Changed\`, 
        callback: (val: V) => V
    ): void

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify which key the listener is on

```js
const car = {
    paint: "red",
    tires: "mrf",
    brakes: "disk",
    bluetooth: true,
    mileage: 7.45
}

type PropChangeListener<T> = {
    on<Key extends string & keyof T>(
        prop: `on${Capitalize<Key>}Changed`, 
        callback: (val: T[Key]) => T[Key]
    ): void
}

declare function registerForChanges<T>(obj: T): PropChangeListener<T>
const carWithListener = registerForChanges(car);
carWithListener.on<'bluetooth'>("onBluetoothChanged", (val: boolean) => !val)
```

TS Playground: https://tsplay.dev/mAv1vW

The statement

```
callback: (val: T[Key]) => T[Key]
```

says, the `callback` is a function that can take any of the type of the attributes of T. So, it can take `string | number | boolean` unless you specify which key the listener is about.

Comment: Thanks. The following code works perfectly after removing `Capitalize` (but I lose the camel-casing). Why and how is `Capitalize`  impacting it?
https://tsplay.dev/mpvkgw

Comment: I can't answer for sure, but it has to be Typescript's ability to infer the `key`. It must be difficult to reverse the mapping. While some may have one to one mapping like "Capitalize" and "Uncapitalize"... we also have "Uppercase"... so, in that case Typescript won't know how to get the exact attribute. If you had used `Uppercase` instead of `Capitalize`. Typescript won't know whether the matching key should be "bluetooth", "blueTooth" or any other variant. So, it just leaves that responsibility to the user. @RajatSaxena

Comment: Because in future there may be more intrinsic mappers that maynot be so easy to reverse infer.